# Serialize enum values as camel cased strings using StringEnumConverter

Tags: c#, enums, json.net, camelcasing

I'm trying to serialize a list of objects to JSON using Newtonsoft's JsonConvert.  My Marker class includes an enum, and I'm trying to serialize it into a camelCase string.  Based on other Stackoverflow questions, I'm trying to use the `StringEnumConverter`:

```
public enum MarkerType
{
    None = 0,
    Bookmark = 1,
    Highlight = 2
}

public class Marker
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter)]
    public MarkerType MarkerType { get; set; }
}
```

This partially works, but my MarkerType string is PascalCase when I call:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(markers, Formatting.None);
```

Result:

```
{
    ...,
    "MarkerType":"Bookmark"
}
```

What I'm really looking for is:

```
{
    ...,
    "MarkerType":"bookmark"
}
```

The [StringEnumConverter docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_converters_stringenumconverter.htm) mention a `CamelCaseText` property, but I'm not sure how to pass that using the `JsonConverterAttribute`.  The following code fails:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter), new object[] { "camelCaseText" }]
```

How do I specify the `CamelCaseText` property for the `StringEnumConverter` in a `JsonConverterAttribute`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[JsonConverterAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) has two constructors, one of which takes a parameter list (`Object[]`).  This maps to the *constructor* of the type from the first parameter.

[StringEnumConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) can handle this with most of its non-default constructors.

[The first one](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter__ctor_2.htm) is obsolete in JSON.net 12+

[The second one](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter__ctor_3.htm) allows you to specify a [NamingStrategy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy.htm) Type; the [CamelCaseNamingStrategy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm) does the trick.  Actually, this is true for three out of the six constructors provided.

Note: [one other constructor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter__ctor_1.htm) breaks the mold, asking for an instance of a NamingStrategy instead of a type.

It would look like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter), typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public MarkerType MarkerType { get; set; }
```

Comment: As of Newtonsoft.Json v 12, there are _5_ non-default constructors, including two that have options for `allowIntegerValues`.

Comment: @WebHead Thanks for the note!  I've updated the answer to take the new constructors into account.